# 'credential-manager' is not a git command

Tags: git, credential-manager

Am on Windows 10 64-bit running git version 2.33.1.windows.1 against Azure repos. Since my last update I get the following error when cloning a rep using TortoiseGit v2.13.0.1 (latest version).

```
git.exe clone --progress -v "https://FenergoProduct@dev.azure.com/FenergoProduct/FlareDocumentation/_git/FlareFenergoRegulationMargin" "C:\Flare\FlareFenergoRegulationMargin"
Cloning into 'C:\Flare\FlareFenergoRegulationMargin'...
git: 'credential-manager' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

The most similar command is
credential-manager-core
```

Does anyone have a simply explanation of how to get rid of this?

Comment: Try `git config --global credential.helper manager-core`.

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately that doesn't seem to work (note the command doesn't give any output):


`$ git config --global credential.helper manager-core`

`$ git pull`
`git: 'credential-manager' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.`

`The most similar command is`
`        credential-manager-core`
`Already up to date.`

Comment: It seems something is wrong with your Windows Credential Manager. Try `git config --global credential.helper store`. It stores the username and password/token in `~/.git-credentials` by default. If you don't want the credential helper, you could also run `git config --global --unset credential.helper` to disable it.

Comment: When I run "git config --global credential.helper store" I don't get any output, what should I see?

Comment: It does not print anything. Try `git clone` and it's expected to ask for username and password/token for once.

Comment: I tried completely uninstalling then reinstalling Git with no results. When I look at Credential Manager in Windows I see under "Generic Credential" a number of values prefixed with "git:". Should I remove these and try again?

Comment: I further tried the following: 1) Deleted Git entirely, including related files in C:\Users\<username> such as .gitconfig. 2) Removed any git credentials from the Windows Credential Manager. 3) Reinstalled git. 4) Ran "git credential-manager-core unconfigure
" 5) Ran (as suggested above) git config --global credential.helper store. 6) Ran (as suggested above) git config --global --unset credential.helper. In all cases I still get the error in the thread subject line when I run a "git pull"

Comment: What does `git config --show-origin credential.helper` print? If it's not empty, it shows the value of `credential.helper` and in which file it's configured.

Answer (score 44):

I started getting the same error messages for every service after my last upgrade.  I made them go away by creating an alias for credential-manager.

```
git config --global alias.credential-manager "credential-manager-core"
```

Other than the error messages, the credential-manager seems to have been working correctly both before and after creating the alias.

Comment: Thanks man! I've tired trying to fix that issue.

Comment: I tried that, didn't work for me on a remote linux machine

Comment: This didn't work for me in 2.44.0.windows.1, but below by @teemo did, https://stackoverflow.com/a/75596870/197141

Answer (score 24):

Execute `git config --global -e` and remove this line in the editor:

```
credential.helper=manager-core
```

`-e` means edit.

Comment: great one! fixed it here... I was messing up with git and got in this situation. :D

Comment: Apparently it was renamed from manager-core to manager in 2.39. Hence removing this old 'manager-core' helps, just as changing it to 'manager' would (until they change it again...)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/76000261/197141

Answer (score 11):

So, no one answer helped me. What i did. I removed manually all section  [credintial] and [alias] from global and system config.
From system config for MINGW64 here:
C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\etc\gitconfig
I deleted this section:

```
[credential]
    helper = manager-core
```

From global config for MINGW64 here:
C:\Users<YourUsersFolder>.gitconfig
I deleted this sections:

```
[alias]
    credential-manager = credential-manager-core
[credential]
    helper = manager-core
```

And I have no this annoing message any more

Comment: This is what worked for me. My repo server is gitlap. I have the following lines on my .gitconfig file:
```[credential "https://server_address.ipip.com"] provider = generic```

Comment: Likewise for myself. I had several entries in the `[credentials]` section, with an incomplete line, and a duplicate. Clearing them out manually solved it.

Answer (score 8):

I also faced this error. how ever I tried more methods and finally below command worked for me. when we replace all config details it will fix. after run below command and then after you can again try git commands like clone, pull, push etc.. then automatically prompt login screen. after login successfully you can work without any issue.

```
git config --global credential.helper manager-core --replace-all
```

Comment: This works for me. I have permanent error  on all actions (fetch, commit, etc) "git-credential-manager-core.exe: no such file or directory". After this command Fetch goes without problem

Comment: After I did so the annoying message become printing twice :)

Comment: I don't think this will work for me since I'm working on a remote (headless) machine where I can't have a login screen open up

Answer (score 4):

credential.helper is related to credential management which stores user usernames and passwords.To unset this use the below command:

```
git config --global --unset credential.helper
```

This will remove the globally configured credential helper.

Answer (score 2):

I edited the .gitconfig file in my user folder and found that it was containing an empty entry in the credential section:

```
[credential]
    helper = 
    helper = manager-core
```

I removed

```
    helper =
```

and it fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

You should check what version of git you are running: I ran into the same issue and figured that I was using MSys2's package of Git instead of GitForWindows, while crediential-manager is exclusive to Microsoft's port of Git.

Use `where git` in your shell to see the actual path used for git.exe:

```
❯ where git
C:\msys64\usr\bin\git.exe
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe
```

Uninstall the MSys2 package for Git if the first line is pointing to `msys64` instead of `Program Files` (like above):

```
❯ pacman -R git
checking dependencies...

Packages (1) git-2.41.0-1

Total Removed Size:  35.97 MiB

:: Do you want to remove these packages? [Y/n] Y
:: Processing package changes...
(1/1) removing git
```

This fixed the credential-manager for me:

```
❯ where git
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe

❯ git credential-manager
Required command was not provided.

git-credential-manager

Usage:
  git-credential-manager [options] [command]

Options:
  --version       Show version information
  -?, -h, --help  Show help and usage information

Commands:
  get          [Git] Return a stored credential
  store        [Git] Store a credential
  erase        [Git] Erase a stored credential
  configure    Configure Git Credential Manager as the Git credential helper
  unconfigure  Unconfigure Git Credential Manager as the Git credential helper
  diagnose     Run diagnostics and gather logs to diagnose problems with Git Credential Manager
  azure-repos  Commands for interacting with the Azure Repos host provider
```

Note that you can't use GitHub without this credential-manager since August 13, 2021:

```
remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021.
remote: Please see https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/about-remote-repositories#cloning-with-https-urls for information on currently recommended modes of authentication.
```

Answer (score 0):

Curiously, I receive the same error message when trying to `push` to a branch that had been deleted on the origin side. Instead of `git commit`, `git push` works in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

I read the answers and tinkered with the files - no-one has written the "why" however...

I don't know how it works, I've just been using git as part of Visual Studio with Azure Devops...

I found there are several gitconfig files on my computer, that was the main problem I didn't know where they all were... so I would change one but it wasn't having an effect.

- **C:\Users<myusername>.gitconfig**
- **C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Git\etc\gitconfig**
- **C:\Program Files\Git\etc\gitconfig**

I opened each of these files and removed the entire **[alias]** section and the entire **[credential]** section... this made the errors go away

As far as I can tell the "credential helper" is a feature that is either deprecated, or no longer required due to integration into the main perhaps.

Given no-one has explained what it means or does or why it's there, all I can do is prod at it.

Answer (score 0):

Install GCM using Homebrew:

```bash
brew install --cask git-credential-manager
```

https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/updating-credentials-from-the-macos-keychain

https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/caching-your-github-credentials-in-git

Answer (score 0):

modified @Teemo and @Raptor's solutions slightly:

ran `git config --global -e`

and altered

`[credential] helper = manager-core`
to
`[credential] helper =  helper = manager`

fixed my issue on windows 11.